# DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH call cause ORA-01422 error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I performed full database import into existing database with identical structure.
After this, call the DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH procedure cause ORA-01422 error.
For example:

```
begin
 DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('SCHEMA_NAME.T_TOP_FRESH_COMMENTS');
end;
```

Error:
  ORA-01422 exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2563
  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2776
  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 2745
  ORA-06512: at line 2

Select bellow returns single row:

```
select * from dba_registered_mviews t where t.name = 'T_TOP_FRESH_COMMENTS'
```

What do errors cause? How can I fix that?
Thanks!

UPD:
Materialized view select doesn’t cause error. The same error repeated for others materialized views.
Script for creating view is listed below:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW T_TOP_FRESH_COMMENTS
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT ROWNUM AS order_comment, id_comment, date_refresh
  FROM (  SELECT c.id_comment, MAX (h.updated) date_refresh
               FROM    t_comment_user c
                 INNER JOIN t_comment_history h  ON c.id_comment = h.id_comment
           WHERE c.published = 'T' AND h.published = 'T' and h.updated is not null GROUP BY c.id_comment
        ORDER BY date_refresh DESC)
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```

UPD1:
I ran completed refresh and recieved the same error:

```
begin
  DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('SCHEMA_NAME.T_TOP_FRESH_COMMENTS','c');
end;
```

I recreated materialized view with REFRESH COMPLETE and this didn't help too.
I tried to purge view log. It is didn't help:

```
begin
dbms_mview.purge_log('SCHEMA_NAME.T_COMMENT_HISTORY',99999,'delete');
end;
```

Comment: There must be some sub query in the materialized view script (`create materialize view` script) which is returning multiple rows where only one is expected. Posting `create materialized view` code will be helpful.

Comment: One of the reason can be stale data in materialize view logs (after the import). Try to execute the complete refresh instead of incremental one first.

Comment: I've got the same problem yesterday.
The following actions did not help:
1) drop & recreate mview log
2) drop & recreate mview
3) select * from sys.snap$, sys.snap_times$, sys.slog$, sys.mlog$ -- no duplicates there

Comment: Have you somehow managed to create two materialized views/tables in more than one schema with the same object name? When you search all/user/dba objects, are there only two objects such that you only have a table called T_TOP_FRESH_COMMENTS and a mat view called T_TOP_FRESH_COMMENTS? Or do you have more than those two?

Comment: Thanks for comment.No, the select:select * from dba_objects where OBJECT_NAME = 'T_TOP_FRESH_COMMENTS' returns only two records. One with object_type = 'TABLE' and another with object_type = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `WHERE ROWNUM <= 10` clause?

Comment: It's for selecting 10 last updated entities.

Comment: What happens if you execute the query of the MV? Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

See the Duplicate Entry in `SYSTEM.DEF$_DESTINATION` Table (Doc ID 2172529.1).